# Wopi integration registration form

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi

As stated in the documentation the WOPI server online calls domains of members of the cloud storage program. The WOPI documentation also contains a link to the registration form https://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstorage. However, when all fields are filled in and try to submit the form it gives an error message. Does anyone know if this is a bug and if so when will this be fixed.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Accoriding to this https://github.com/Microsoft/Office-Online-Test-Tools-and-Documentation/issues/346 it should be fixed now